# запись в базу аякс

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

есть форма добавления

```
<div id="chat-input" class="msg-input">
            <textarea autocomplete="off" placeholder="Введите сообщение:" id="messaging-widget-textarea" class="msg-input__textarea"></textarea>
            <div class="btn-box">
                <div class="file-upload-chat">
                    <label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="input__button"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

и роут

```
Route::post('/support/message/{id}', 'SupportController@newMessage')->name('addMessage');
```

как записать в базу записи, делал так, но выдает

```
POST http://one.extremje.bget.ru/sd-admin/support/message/2 500 (Internal Server Error)

$("#chat-input .input__button").click(function(){
        var message = $(this).closest("#chat-input").find("#messaging-widget-textarea").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'message' : message
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуй поменять это:

```
Route::post('/support/message/{id}', 'SupportController@newMessage')->name('addMessage');
```

на это:

```
Route::post("/support/message/{id}", 'SupportController@newMessage')->name('addMessage');
```

но ещё правильнее, посмотри во вкладке `Network` в браузере на ответ сервера на данный `ajax` запрос

Comment: в роуте мне кажется все ок, почему-то мне кажется в ajax url неверный, а как подставить этот не могу понять /support/message/{id}

Comment: а что выводиться во вкладке `network`?

Comment: разобрался. неправильно передавал _token